# Melting values of multiple columns to single column based on another column value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like :

```
A      B    1   4
alpha   1   2   3
beta    4   5   6
gamma   4   8   9
```

```
df= pd.DataFrame([['alpha',1,2,3], ['beta', 4,5,6], ['gamma',4,8,9]], columns=['A','B', 1, 4])
```

I an now trying to map value of column 'B' to -> 1 and 4. The result dataframe should look like:

```
A      B    value
alpha   1   2
beta    4   6
gamma   4   9
​

I tried melt and stack but couldn't figure it out.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `lookup`

```
df['value']=df.lookup(df.index,df.B.astype(str))
df
       A  B  1  4  value
0  alpha  1  2  3      2
1   beta  4  5  6      6
2  gamma  4  8  9      9
```